# MySQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have run this query through SQL validitions online and such and it says it is valid... but running the query itself on my machine ... it keeps giving me the error: `#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

```
SELECT i.pmt_status, i.profile_id, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT (ut.toolid) SEPARATOR  ',' ) AS tools
FROM profile_login i
LEFT JOIN profile_usertools ut ON i.profile_id = ut.profile_id
WHERE i.inactive =0
AND ut.enabled =1
AND i.profile_id = ( 5633, 5665, 5652, 5638, 5641, 5614, 5614, 5632, 5634, 5614, 5650, 5614, 5599 ) 
GROUP BY ut.profile_id
```

And I am not sure how to fix this. I thought I was following everything correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change query

```
AND i.profile_id in ( 5633, 5665, 5652, 5638, 5641, 5614, 5614, 5632, 5634, 5614, 5650, 5614, 5599 )
```